# Add button to crystal reports viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using c# to display some crystal reports in my asp.net web app. I would like to add a custom button to the toolbar to go back a page. How do I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: is there something wrong with the existing previous button? You can replace the graphic by changing it in the aspnet_client folder of IIS but you will have to search for it, I don't know exactly where it is in there.

Comment: I should have said previous web page not report page.

Comment: Well, you might look in there anyway, that viewer is just html and css so you could probably hack a button in there if there is no api for it. I'm not recommending it though, the browser has a perfectly good back button already and I can't imagine users will expect a page back button in their report viewer toolbar.

Comment: *I should have said* Then update your question as well - comments disappear.